# How to remember changes of html attributes which are changed by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery function which changes the class of element

```
 $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("ul").find("a").parent().removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
```

but when i refresh page, there are no changes added. How to remember them, even when user refreshes page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, in sites which have no server side application, users do not expect page state to remain when using page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your `active` items using some type of `data store` (`Cookies`, `Local Storage`, `QueryString`). Though, there may be ***another/better*** solution if you give more context.

***Update based off comment:***

Embed a hidden element in each tab that maps to a tab `class`name or `id`. Then create a simple algorithm that matches the currently displayed tab content with the associated tab nav item.

Comment: i am using bootstrap tabs plugin. and want to save tab clicked. That what i want to do. What is the easiest way?

Comment: "Embed a hidden element in each tab", but thit element will dissaper after refreshing page too? Or i undersstand something wrong?

Comment: *Each* tab link has a content area that it is associated with. Thus, add a hidden element in *each content area* that has a `class`name or an `id` with the value equal to the tab link class name.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to keep track of the classnames by storing the info in a cookie or in `localStorage`.

Comment: Could you advise way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this three functions to store your configuration

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "Hello World!"); //saves to the database, key/value
localStorage.removeItem("name"); //deletes the matching item from the database
localStorage.getItem("name"); // gets the item back
```

Comment: thans for advise, but I have a condition in task - do not use html5.